# AWS Lambda Cold Start with java taking more than 10 sec

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, cold-start

I have lambda function on AWS in java with following specs:

Code Size: 35 MB
Function Memory: 3GB
Timeout: 5 min
Cloudwatch warming schedule: 1 minute

I am using [JRestless](https://github.com/bbilger/jrestless) Wrapper.

Following is my RequestHandler Method:

```
    public class RequestHandler extends GatewayRequestObjectHandler {
    static ResourceConfig resourceConfig = new ResourceConfig().register(GatewayFeature.class)
            .register(RequestContextFilter.class).packages("com.xyz.abcd");

    static RequestHandler bc = new RequestHandler();
    static {
        resourceConfig.property("contextConfigLocation", "classpath:web-application-context.xml");
        bc.init(resourceConfig);
        bc.start();
    }

    /**
     * 
     */
    public RequestHandler() {
        super();
    }
}
```

Inspite of having a warming of as minimum as 1 minute lambda function cold starts atleast **20 times** in **24 hrs** and each time it takes more than **10sec**.

Comment: Issues related to cold starts are usually caused by things *outside* of the handler. So you might want to look at that part first.

Comment: Is your function in a vpc?

Answer (score 0):

If I undestand your setup correctly, you're using a warm up invocation that runs every minute.

What is the concurrency limit of your function? If you have more than one invocations reaching your lambda with a concurrency level higher than 1, then you'll get a cold start for each one of the extra invocations / requests.

That's a very typical scenario with bursty traffic.

If that is indeed the case, you'll have to issue a higher number of invocations (close to the number of the ones you expect your service to receive) for your warm up phase.

Make sure that you're also short circuiting these to avoid unnecessary costs and potential downstream pressure.

The other reason why you might be experiencing cold starts is that the hardware or container your function runs on has issues and had to die i.e. factors outside your control. Even in these cases though, the setup described above would help reduce the number of cold starts to a minimum.